# VirtualBox changed how elementary OS looks

Tags: themes, virtualbox

I installed VirtualBox on my PC a few days ago just to tinker around with it and now the whole operating system has changed how it looks. The dock looks different, some of the icons are missing, the Software Center has disappeared. I don't know what happened. I use this OS mainly for Internet browsing and some light coding. The OS was working perfectly fine a few days ago but after installing VirtualBox and restarting, it has all changed. When I installed elementary OS, it was on version 0.3.2 and it still says the same now so I don't know why it looks completely different.
I hope the image might help. Thanks! [image: Desktop]

Comment: How did you install virtualbox? Seems like it changed you theme settings.

Comment: i went on the website, and i downloaded the ubuntu 14.01 version

Comment: wait! no youre right! thanks so much! i just changed them all back to elementary. thanks :) but i didnt go anywhere near the theme settings?

Comment: Could you post your steps to fix as an answer for the next person?

Comment: It also happened to me yesterday after installing Virtualbox. I install it via `terminal sudo apt-get install virtualbox` now the main font is changed and looks much bigger. also once my computer freezed so I had to restart it manually. I am using elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya (64-bit) Built on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @TomGuy It may have been a bug of some kind :)